# csd ingame info

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a countdown in user.setGame, can someone help me create the code for the countdown?

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();


bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
  user.setGame(countdown)
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you counting down? Minutes? Seconds? Are you counting down to a specific time/date or relative to when the countdown started? What have you tried? It's hard to give any meaningful advice without knowing exactly what is being asked. Please take a look at [ask] and edit your question to improve it and make it more answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by 'countdown' you mean a specific amount of time before the game is set, you can easily use something like [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). Here's an example using your code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();


bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
  setTimeout(() => {
    bot.user.setGame('Online and ready to roll!');
  }, 60000); // Time in Milliseconds (60000 = 60 seconds = 1 minute)
});
```

EDIT: With the new comment, I now understand what you're going for. Here's something that should do you fine, using some of the methods above and a little thing called [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). We're also going to use an awesome module called [pretty-ms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-ms), which will make our time left readable. I'll provide two examples, one using pretty-ms and one not.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const pms = require('pretty-ms');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const endTime = new Date("May 20 2018 2:00 PM");

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
  const countdownGame = setInterval(() => {
    if (endTime.getTime() - Date.now() < 0) {
      clearInterval(countdownGame);
      bot.user.setGame('Time\'s Up!');
    }
    // Get the endDate minus the current date, and then make the milliseconds pretty
    // Remove { compact: true } for a full value. You can see all the options
    // available on the module's page.
    bot.user.setGame(pms(endTime.getTime() - Date.now(), { compact: true }));
  }, 60000); // Time in Milliseconds before rerun (60000 = 60 seconds = 1 minute)
  // Due to Discord ratelimiting, you may need to change this value to only update every 
  // 2 minutes or more.
});
```

It should be noted that when doing `new Date("May 20 2018 2:00 PM");`, this is just one of the many ways you can set the date to the future. You can also use .setHours like André Paulo showed in his example. Checkout the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation on MDN for ways to set more dates!

If, for some reason, you don't want to use pretty-ms (it's a *pretty* useful module bu-dum tissss I'm sorry), here's an example of the setGame line not using pms.

```
// Hours
bot.user.setGame((endTime.getTime() - Date.now())/1000/60/60);
// Minutes
bot.user.setGame((endTime.getTime() - Date.now())/1000/60);
// Seconds
bot.user.setGame((endTime.getTime() - Date.now())/1000);
```

Please keep in mind that w/o using the module, when the time ends or goes below your set, it WILL include decimals. I suggest using [Number#toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for that.

EDIT 2: Also, André Paulo is correct in that [ClientUser#setGame](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.3.2/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setGame) is depreciated. As of 1.11.3, it's now [ClientUser#setPresence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.3.2/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence).

Happy coding!

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer! What i'm trying to do is displaying the countdown in bot.user.setGame(). So if for example the countdown is set for 12h, it will display something like this every minute: 11:59 11:58 11:57...

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense! I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Alright, I've edited it with the appropriate answer. Hopefully this solves your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i really appreciate the details, but there's a problem. it displays only "-1d" as result in game info. There's a way to show result like: 27hours and 16minutes?

Comment: ps: i have no problem using pretty-ms

Comment: Yes. To display it as "27 hours and 16 minutes" (the formatting, not that exact time haha), use the `verbose` option. It's listed in the pretty-ms docs.

Comment: Dude... Please read the options for pretty-ms. Notice how the options currently have "compact" in them. Replace that with any option you'd like to put.

Answer (score 1):

`user.setGame()` is deprecated.
You might want look at [`user.setPresence()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence)

```
bot.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with discord.js' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

So something like this would work:

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready!');
    var hours = 12;

    let now = new Date();
    var later = new Date();
    later.setHours(now.getHours()+hours);

    bot.user.setPresence({game: {name: hours+':00'});
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        let left = new Date(later - new Date());
        if(left >= 0){
            bot.user.setPresence({game: {name: left.getHours() + ":" + left.getMinutes()});
        } else {
            // time is up
        }
    }, 60000);
});
```

*(untested)*

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer!
What i'm trying to do is displaying the countdown in the game name.
So if for example the countdown is set for 12h, it will display something like this every minute: 11:59 11:58 11:57...

Comment: that wouldn't be possible. Can't remember exactly but there is a rate limit for updating game Status.
Edit: might be 5 times per 60 seconds

Comment: @CorpyS take a look at my answer again, I've updated it

Comment: thanks for the edit, there's one problem.
after a minute the display changed from 12:00 to 14:58 and then 14:57 14:56....